# JS not working properly in firefox

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, firefox, applet

I am using qzprint API for printing labels in my open cart extension. Everything was working fine but suddenly it stopped working on FF. In Internet explorer it works fine. If i add alerts in my functions of applet it works fine on firefox as well but not sure why not with out alerts. here is my code.

**calling applet functions in my header.tpl**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
deployQZ('<?php echo HTTP_CATALOG ?>');
useDefaultPrinter();
<script>
```

**Applet file containing functions**

```
function deployQZ(path) {
//alert("alert for printing label");
    pathApplet = path + 'java/qz-print.jar';
    pathJnlp = path + 'java/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp';
    var attributes = {id: "qz", code:'qz.PrintApplet.class', 
        archive: pathApplet, width:1, height:1};
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: pathJnlp, 
        cache_option:'plugin', disable_logging:'false', 
        initial_focus:'false'};
    if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.7+") == true) {}
    else if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.6+") == true) {
        attributes['archive'] = 'java/jre6/qz-print.jar';
        parameters['jnlp_href'] = 'java/jre6/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp';
    }
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');
}

/**
* Automatically gets called when applet has loaded.
*/
function qzReady() {
    // Setup our global qz object
    window["qz"] = document.getElementById('qz');
    //var title = document.getElementById("title");
    if (qz) {
        try {
            //title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML + " " + qz.getVersion();
            //document.getElementById("content").style.background = "#F0F0F0";
        } catch(err) { // LiveConnect error, display a detailed meesage
            document.getElementById("content").style.background = "#F5A9A9";
            alert("ERROR:  \nThe applet did not load correctly.  Communication to the " + 
                "applet has failed, likely caused by Java Security Settings.  \n\n" + 
                "CAUSE:  \nJava 7 update 25 and higher block LiveConnect calls " + 
                "once Oracle has marked that version as outdated, which " + 
                "is likely the cause.  \n\nSOLUTION:  \n  1. Update Java to the latest " + 
                "Java version \n          (or)\n  2. Lower the security " + 
                "settings from the Java Control Panel.");
      }
  }
}

    /**
* Returns is the applet is not loaded properly
*/
function isLoaded() {
    if (!qz) {
        alert('Error:\n\n\tPrint plugin is NOT loaded!');
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            if (!qz.isActive()) {
                alert('Error:\n\n\tPrint plugin is loaded but NOT active!');
                return false;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Error:\n\n\tPrint plugin is NOT loaded properly!');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

    function useDefaultPrinter() {
    //alert("alert for printing label");
    if (isLoaded()) {
        // Searches for default printer
        qz.findPrinter();

        // Automatically gets called when "qz.findPrinter()" is finished.
        window['qzDoneFinding'] = function() {
            // Alert the printer name to user
            var printer = qz.getPrinter();
            //alert(printer !== null ? 'Default printer found: "' + printer + '"':
                //'Default printer ' + 'not found');
            document.getElementById("name_printer").innerHTML = 'Default printer found: "' + printer + '"'; 
            // Remove reference to this function
            window['qzDoneFinding'] = null;
            defaultFound = true;
        };
    }
}
```

As u can see in my deployqz() and usedefaultprinter() functions i have alert on first line which is in comments if its commented it doesn't work in fire fox and if not commented than it works fine. With comments i get alert message from isLoaded() function "Print plugin is NOT loaded properly!".

Also in my console i get this

An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing

Comment: Looks like a timing issue. Change `if (isLoaded()) { ...}`  to if (isLoaded()) { ...} else { setTimeout(useDefaultPrinter,300); }`

Comment: @mplungjan even if i dont call useDefaultPrinter() it gives me error so i think its down to the deployqz()..

Comment: Try adding `var qz;` to before the first function, then change `window["qz"] =` to `qz =` - I do not actually see any `qzReady()`anywhere so it is likely called by the applet. Do you have errors in the console? Can you defer and call qzReady() the way I called useDefaultPrinter?

Comment: @mplungjan i have no errors in console.. let me try what u asked for

Comment: @mplungjan it didnt work :(

Comment: @mplungjan Is it down to JS async function because if i add alerts it works fine..

Comment: You do not have a JS async function. You have an applet trying to call a js function before it is ready

Comment: @mplungjan  usedefaultprinter() is having issue as it called "isLoaded()" and is called before applet is loaded properly so what can i do ?

Comment: Use setTimeout where needed

Comment: @mplungjan can u please give me a sample of using settimeout for qzready() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. If the qzReady is called by the applet when ready, put useDefaultPrinter inside that function.
2. if isLoaded takes some time, call useDefaultPrinter in there too using setTimeout

Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
deployQZ('<?php echo HTTP_CATALOG ?>');
<script>
```

**Applet file containing functions**

```
var qz;

function deployQZ(path) {
    pathApplet = path + 'java/qz-print.jar';
    pathJnlp = path + 'java/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp';
    var attributes = {id: "qz", code:'qz.PrintApplet.class', 
        archive: pathApplet, width:1, height:1};
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: pathJnlp, 
        cache_option:'plugin', disable_logging:'false', 
        initial_focus:'false'};
    if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.7+") == true) {}
    else if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.6+") == true) {
        attributes['archive'] = 'java/jre6/qz-print.jar';
        parameters['jnlp_href'] = 'java/jre6/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp';
    }
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');
}

/**
* Automatically gets called when applet has loaded.
*/
function qzReady() {
    // Setup our global qz object
    qz = document.getElementById('qz');
    if (qz) {
        try {
          useDefaultPrinter();
        } catch(err) { // LiveConnect error, display a detailed meesage
            document.getElementById("content").style.background = "#F5A9A9";
            alert("ERROR:  \nThe applet did not load correctly.  Communication to the " + 
                "applet has failed, likely caused by Java Security Settings.  \n\n" + 
                "CAUSE:  \nJava 7 update 25 and higher block LiveConnect calls " + 
                "once Oracle has marked that version as outdated, which " + 
                "is likely the cause.  \n\nSOLUTION:  \n  1. Update Java to the latest " + 
                "Java version \n          (or)\n  2. Lower the security " + 
                "settings from the Java Control Panel.");
      }
   }
   else { setTimeout(useDefaultPrinter,300); }
}

    /**
* Returns is the applet is not loaded properly
*/
function isLoaded() {
    if (!qz) {
        alert('Error:\n\n\tPrint plugin is NOT loaded!');
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            if (!qz.isActive()) {
                alert('Error:\n\n\tPrint plugin is loaded but NOT active!');
                return false;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Error:\n\n\tPrint plugin is NOT loaded properly!');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function useDefaultPrinter() {
    //alert("alert for printing label");
    if (isLoaded()) {
        // Searches for default printer
        qz.findPrinter();

        // Automatically gets called when "qz.findPrinter()" is finished.
        window['qzDoneFinding'] = function() {
            // Alert the printer name to user
            var printer = qz.getPrinter();
            //alert(printer !== null ? 'Default printer found: "' + printer + '"':
                //'Default printer ' + 'not found');
            document.getElementById("name_printer").innerHTML = 'Default printer found: "' + printer + '"'; 
            // Remove reference to this function
            window['qzDoneFinding'] = null;
            defaultFound = true;
        };
    }
    else { setTimeout(useDefaultPrinter,300); }
}
```

Comment: waoww it worked.. Can u please explain how did u do that? please elaborate what was actually wrong? Thanks alot!

Comment: See update - the main problem was calling useDefaultPrinter right after deploy. Since it was async, there was a good chance it was nor ready until qzReady had run anyway